# What are the "picture control" values shown in EXIF info from Nikon D5500

Tags: nikon, metadata, program-mode, nikon-d5500

Exif info for picture control sharpness and hue show large values as seen in attached : eg +-127 or +-124 etc
Is this correct and what does this indicate

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you shoot JPEG and this is "Picture Control" your camera apply to photo. Those values represent how much particular setting is applied, based on the "style" you select.
Here is [Nikon USA web site](https://www.nikonusa.com/en/learn-and-explore/a/tips-and-techniques/picture-controls-step-by-step.html) with more explanations:

> Vivid
>
> For distinct, colorful, fresh-looking images with just the right
>   emphasis on your subject’s contrast and sharpening. Compared with
>   Standard, Vivid bestows a more glamorous overall impression. It’s
>   ideal for situations where you wish to emphasize primary colors, such
>   as colorful fashions, city streets, fresh fruits and floral
>   arrangements. With Vivid, you can adjust sharpening, contrast,
>   brightness, saturation, and hue (coloration) individually. Quick
>   Adjust enables easy, balanced adjustments.

You can adjust them on this way (same web page):

> Quick Adjust
>
> Quick Adjust makes it easy to achieve well-balanced adjustments.
>   With sharpening, contrast, and saturation, five levels of
>   modification (-2 to +5) are applied automatically. Increasing a value
>   on the plus side strengthens the characteristics of each Picture
>   Control while movement on the minus side lessens the effect.
>   Moreover, after using Quick Adjust, you can carry out finer, more
>   detailed modifications to each item to suit your particular
>   preferences and get the exact results you require. Each Picture
>   Control (except Flat, Neutral and Monochrome) allows you to use Quick
>   Adjust for adjustments.